# Vercel.com Hosting: Development & Production URLs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mongodb-atlas, vercel

My server.js file has the following code

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
//const fs = require('fs');
//const fileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const passport = require('passport');
const authenticate = require('./authenticate');
const config = require('./config');

const router = express.Router();
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const poemsRouter = require('./routes/poems');

const app = express();
app.use(history());
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());

//connect to mongodb dova
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const client = mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl, { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false 
    }, ()=>{
    console.log('DOVA connection has been made');
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error('App starting error:', err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});

router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.json({ message: 'API Initialized!'});
});

const port = process.env.API_PORT || 8081;
app.use('/', router);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/poems', poemsRouter);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next)=>{
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

var server = app.listen(port, ()=>{//221020 pre added 'var server = '
    console.log(`api running on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = server; //221020 added this line
```

Then my **vue > views > Poems.vue** has this part of code in its script

```
fetchPoems(){
        return axios({
          method: 'get',
          **url: 'http://localhost:8081/poems',**
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
        .then((res)=>{
          this.poems = res.data.poems;
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
```

When I locally 'npm run build' and 'serve -s dist' to preview a production level static app everything works well, i.e. the 'poems' are fetched from my MongoDB Atlas database and served. However, on the vercel.com hosting platform, with the same configurations, no 'poems' are being fetched.

I first thought that I needed to remove the string **'http://localhost:8081/'** from the **vue > views > Poems.vue fetchPoems() function,** but still the poems weren't being loaded.

**PS Assist: Am going nuts**

My question in short is how do I deal with development & production level routing on a MEVN stack given then code above.

Answer (score 0):

In *Poems.vue* the `url` should be `/poems` and NOT `http://localhost:8081/poems`.

Browser will use correct domain automatically. You need to put `/` at the beginning to indicate that the path is absolute, and not relative to the current page.

Complete code:

```
fetchPoems(){
        return axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: '/poems',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
        .then((res)=>{
          this.poems = res.data.poems;
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
```

Comment: Hie boss, ps visit this git repo https://github.com/Yacie/dova-poems for my minified app and help me debug. This version is now also hosted at https://dova-poems.vercel.app/. Wud appreciate if you also upload yo working copy to vercel.com so that we are on the same environment

Comment: Spoke to vercel support. They notified me that vercel is a serverless platform; hence my approach of nodejs, express & axios will not work.

Configured the app to fetch data via serverless functions **"BOOM!!"** it was working after after a combined 12hrs of debuggin & testin & amending commits

See a working mini-app on github.com/Yacie/dova-poems

And The main app on [dova.vercel.app][1]

  [1]: https://dova.vercel.app